# Laravel, Vue.js2 and Filepond. Image not saving on form submission

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, filepond

So I am currently working with **Laravel and Vue**, and I am trying to create an employee form that allows a user to create and save the details of an employee. Now the thing is, when I save the form, everything saves nicely and as it should, but my only problem now is that the image that I drag and drop or place in the **Filepond** space doesn't save. **It is worth noting my [Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si8lj.png).** I have been stuck on this for days, and would really appreciate some help. thank you in advance.

Below is the code for the employee form in my Employee.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">
              {{ $t('employees.list.create.form_title') }}
            </h3>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-header -->

          <!-- form start -->
          <form role="form" @submit.prevent="saveEmployee" @keydown="form.onKeydown($event)">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="employeeName">{{ $t('employees.common.employee_name') }}
                    <span class="required">*</span></label>
                  <input id="employeeName" v-model="form.employeeName" type="text" class="form-control"
                    :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('employeeName') }" name="employeeName" :placeholder="
                      $t('employees.common.employee_name_placeholder')
                    " />
                  <has-error :form="form" field="employeeName" />
                </div>
                <!-- upload profile photo -->
                <file-pond
                  name="image"
                  ref="pond"
                  allow-multiple="false"
                  instant-upload="true"
                  :accepted-file-types="[
                    'image/jpeg',
                    'image/png',
                    'image/jpg'
                  ]"
                  :max-file-size="3"
                  @processfile="onProcessFile"
                />

              </div>
              
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
            <div class="card-footer">
              <v-button :loading="form.busy" class="btn btn-hero btn-primary">
                <i class="fas fa-save" /> {{ $t('common.save') }}
              </v-button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Form from 'vform'
import vueFilePond from "vue-filepond";

// Import plugins
import FilePondPluginFileValidateType from "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type/dist/filepond-plugin-file-validate-type.esm.js";
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.esm.js";

// Import styles
import "filepond/dist/filepond.min.css";
import "filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css";

// Create FilePond component
const FilePond = vueFilePond(
  FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
  FilePondPluginImagePreview
);

export default {
  data: () => ({
    form: new Form({
      employeeName: '',
      image: '',
    }),
  }),
  components: {
    FilePond
  },
  methods: {

    onProcessFile(file) {
      const uploadedFile = this.$refs.pond.getFiles()[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = () => {
        this.form.image = reader.result;
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(uploadedFile.file);
    },


    // save employee
    async saveEmployee() {
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('image', this.form.image);

      await this.form
        .post(window.location.origin + '/api/employees', formData)
        .then(() => {
          toast.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: this.$t('employees.list.create.success_msg'),
          })
          this.$router.push({ name: 'employees.index' })
        })
        .catch(() => {
          toast.fire({ type: 'error', title: this.$t('common.error_msg') })
        })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Below is also the store method in my EmployeeController.php i use to save the data in the form:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // validate request
        $this->validate($request, [
            'employeeName' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:employees,name'
        ]);

        try {
            // generate code
            $code = 1;
            $lastEmployee = Employee::latest()->first();
            if ($lastEmployee) {
                $code = $lastEmployee->emp_id + 1;
            }

            // upload thumbnail and set the name
            $imageName = '';
            if ($request->image) {
                $imageName = time().'.'.explode('/', explode(':', substr($request->image, 0, strpos($request->image, ';')))[1])[1];
                Image::make($request->image)->save(public_path('images/employees/').$imageName);
            }

            // create employee
            Employee::create([
                'name' => $request->employeeName,
                'emp_id' => $code,
                'image_path' => $imageName
            ]);

            return $this->responseWithSuccess('Employee added successfully');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->responseWithError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My routes/api.php file for the all matters involving employees is as follows:

```
    // Employee routes
    Route::get('/employees/search', [EmployeeController::class, 'search']);
    Route::get('/all-employees', [EmployeeController::class, 'allEmployees']);
    Route::apiResource('employees', EmployeeController::class);
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).